# CSS3 Animation On Link Click, not Page Load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, animation

I have a reddit-like app in which I want a CSS3 animation to trigger whenever I `downvote` an item.  I have it set up so the animation works properly whenever a `downvote`, but is recorded, but it also triggers on the initial page load.  Any attempts to have this not happen have made the animation not work under any circumstances.

The animation is triggered with the following on my `erb` page:

```
<div class="animations">
  <%= image_tag "ballerino.png", class: "fixed animation-left-to-right", id: "to-animate", style: "margin-top: 80px; width: 300px" %>

  <script>
  $(".downvote").on('click', function() {
    $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
    window.location.reload(false);
  });
  </script>

</div> <!-- animations -->
```

I also have the following definitions in my `application.scss` page that I have tried to use with the jQuery:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this so the animation does not trigger when the page initially loads?

Note:  I'm not complicating the matter with the actual `CSS` for the animation itself, because the animation **is** working properly, just one extra time.  If anyone thinks it would help I can add it, but I really think the issue is to do with my `JavaScript`.

Comment: you already have the `animation-left-to-right` class on the img tag. so it triggers when the page loads. removing that might help since you are applying it via jQuery anyway.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange, the animation runs once when you initially navigate to the page (initial page load) and then again when it should (on `downvote`).  If I remove `animation-left-to-right` from the image's `class` then it just stays on the page as a fixed image with no movement no matter what.

Comment: add `animation-play-state: paused;` to your 'animation-left-to-right' class ... then on downvote use jQuery to change the CSS to `animation-play-state:running` instead of adding the class.

Comment: that will prevent it from running the animation on page load and only trigger it on click.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange, added a line to my jQuery saying `  $("#to-animate").css("animation-play-state", "running");` and put `style: "animation-play-state: paused"` on the image and it didn't stop the animation from running on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the animation is running at load because you added the class to the image tag, so when it loads it does whatever that class do (on this case animate).
Ankith is correct, if you dont want to run at load, that class name should be only fixed.
It may be silly, but since you already have a class, try to add an empty space at the begining on your javascript call, that could be why is not doing anything, because you end up with a class named 'fixedanimation-left-to-right'

try

```
 <script>
 $(".downvote").on('click', function() {
 $('#to-animate').addClass(' animation-left-to-right');
  window.location.reload(false);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I know that the presence of `animation-left-to-right` is why it's running at load, but without that there (with the previous javascript or with the new one you suggested with the space) nothing happens to the image at all when downvote is clicked.  It just remains stationary on the page.

Comment: if you check on the chrome tools, is it adding the class correctly (if you dont add it)?

Comment: I hit `downvote` and then checked in the `elements` tab of the `inspect` window as well as the `view page source` version.  Neither had the `animation-left-to-right` on it.  Then I thought maybe this could be because of the `window.location.reload(false)` refreshing the page, so I got rid of that just to check and it still didn't appear...

Comment: Did you tried to remove also the fixed class, so you wont have a class at all and then add it later with the jquery?

Comment: Without the `fixed` it shoves all the content down on the page.  I'm trying to get this to happen on top of the existing content...

Comment: yes, i know its not what do you want in the end, but as a test, to see if it appears or not, you can call the fixed display as an id if that solves it

Comment: Did you try to change it to raw javascript instead of jquery using
    document.getElementById("to-animate").className = "animation-left-to-right"

Comment: I tried this `<script>
  $(".downvote").on('click', function() {
   document.getElementById("to-animate").className = "animation-left-to-right"
   window.location.reload(false);
   });
 </script>` and got the same result (a stationary image).

Comment: you are mixing jquery with raw js, you should try the click function also to be raw js, cause what doesnt seems to work is the click function and its not adding the class to the right element.

Comment: I can kind of get by with JQuery, but I don't know Javascript yet.  How do you "phrase" that in pure JS?