# CSS3 Animation Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, animation

I have a voting structure in my app and I am trying to get an animation to trigger whenever something is downvoted.  I have the following item in my html/erb:

```
  <%= image_tag "ballerino.png", class: "fixed no-show", id: "to-animate", style: "margin-top: 80px; width: 300px" %>
```

And the following javascript:

```
<script>
  $(".downvote").on('click', function() {
     $('#to-animate').removeClass('no-show');
     $('#to-animate').addClass('animation-left-to-right');
     window.location.reload(false);
  });
</script>
```

Here is the html/erb for the `.downvote` which, when clicked, should trigger the animation:

```
<div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", vote_up_joke_path(joke), class: 'upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
<div class="width: 100%"><h3 id="joke_<%= joke.id %>_votes" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong><%= joke.plusminus %></strong></h3></div>
<div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", vote_down_joke_path(joke), class: 'downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
```

Finally, here's my SCSS:

```
/* VOTING ANIMATIONS */

.no-show {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.animation-left-to-right{
  animation: l-r-ballerina linear 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: l-r-ballerina linear 5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*IE 10+*/
}

@keyframes l-r-ballerina{
  0% { transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-moz-keyframes l-r-ballerina{
  0% { -moz-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -moz-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -moz-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ;  }
  30% { -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -moz-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -moz-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% {-moz-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% { -webkit-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -webkit-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -webkit-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -webkit-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -webkit-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { -webkit-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-o-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% { -o-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -o-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -o-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -o-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -o-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { -o-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}

@-ms-keyframes l-r-ballerina {
  0% { -ms-transform:  translate(-400px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ; }
  10% { -ms-transform:  translate(-200px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  20% { -ms-transform:  translate(-100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  30% { -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  40% { -ms-transform:  translate(100px,0px)  rotate(10deg) ; }
  50% { -ms-transform:  translate(300px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
  100% { -ms-transform:  translate(3000px,0px)  rotate(-10deg) ; }
}
```

I have been working on this issue on and off for months and can't get it to work.  I had it closer to working before (see my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175129/css3-animation-on-link-click-not-page-load) post), but for some reason even what I had then isn't working (hence the separate post). Any help is appreciated to get this working.

Comment: Just a quick guess: does it have to do with `animation-play-state: paused`? I don't see a place where it's being unpaused.

Comment: @LarsW, not sure why it was `paused` to begin with, but I removed that line and it didn't change the result (which is the image unfortunately just sitting there).